# Control bi-direction of an actuator by two solar panels

Tags: relay, actuator

I have two solar panels and would like to control a small actuator in both directions. I reckon I need to use relays but hard to make a solid circuit with these two independent power sources.

Would it be possible to make each solar panel supplies into one direction?

I have tried to draw a schematic that I was thinking of. The solar panel and actuator are small DIY elements, so no specific parts are really determined yet.

[image]

Comment: Please draw a schematic and add datasheet link to the actuator.

Comment: @winny thansk. I have added a schematic. Could you have a look?

Comment: Still unclear unfortunately. Are you trying to track the sun? Datasheet to the actuator? Is it reversible?

Comment: @winny Sorry and thanks for your patience. Yes, the idea is to use a linear actuator and depending on the sun's direction(east/west) each solar panel trigger the actuator different direction. I couldn't find the datasheet but considering this kind of 12V model : https://www.ubuy.ke/en/product/3SYQXPI-homend-dc-12v-14-inch-stroke-linear-actuator-with-mounting-bracket-350mm-6000n-1320lb-maximum-load-f

Comment: I built an idetical system when I was 15. I used two photodiodes pointed at about 30 degree apart from solar panel axis and comparators. If left was significantly higher than right (or vice versa), I used a SPST relay to turn on the motor. After it came a DPDT relay to act as H-bridge to reverse polarity if it needed to move in opposite direction. I had some low pass filtering but it was still a bit wonky when clouds came and went. On a clear day however, it tracked beautifully. Today, I would have used an MCU instead.

Comment: @winny Thanks alot, your experience gave me a good hint. I think I will try with comparator relay module first. Though it seems hard to find DPDT attached, but if I use with SMTP support +V/-V outputs might work well.

Comment: My best advice would be to go for an MCU with a pre-calculated solar calendar for your latitude and longitude and just set time and date. It would however need an encoder to have position feedback. If you go the analog route, perhaps a current mirror to have one photodiode current cancel out the other, or use opamps. You don't want fixed levels as clouds will be present and lower the current for both despite no movement is desired.